# Sitefinity search index sfProgressTaskDescription

Tags: sitefinity

Within Sitefinity during the reindexing task can the css class sfProgressTaskDescription be updated? Can I use the `ResourceClassId` and update that text n the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using `htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values` and setting the  ResourceClassId  value.